# I'm trying to Check if a certain WebElement is present through chrome drive in java after checking the page is loaded, but it's not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nosuchelementexception, findelement

I'm trying to Check if a certain WebElement is present through chrome drive in java after checking the page is loaded.
even though the page is loaded and the element is present the driver can't locate it and I get a
NoSuchElementException.
if I'll let it run more time it would probably make it but that's not possible with logic of my code because I'm checking if this element is present while the page is loaded to see if something is clickable (when I over it looks clickable but when I click it nothing happen so something like "isClickable" {if that's a thing} probably won't work) and gets me to the right place.

part of my code:

```
while (true) {
                    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                    if (js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete")) {
                        try {
                            if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div")).isEnabled()) {
                                inProfilePictureTab = true;
                                toBreak = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        } catch (NoSuchElementException exception) {
                            warningLabelChanger("Profile picture isn't clickable, try something else");
                            toBreak = true;
                            break;


                        } catch (NullPointerException exception2) {

                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(Constants.SLEEP_TIME);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: `js.executeScript("return document.readyState")` is just that page source has loaded, not that the final page content is ready and redered. Pages which load with JS take longer and need extra synchronisation.  Try and implicit wait for simplicity.  Beyond that, validate if your element is in an `iframe` or `shadowroot`. Both of these need special handling. Finally, are you sure your element is present at runtime? - Your using an absolute xpath and as such it's fragile. Even things like the window size can break xpaths like that.

Comment: @RichEdwards I'm still learning so I don't know how to do that, could you help me with that?

Comment: Implicit wait - add this once after you create your driver: `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;`

Comment: for `iframe` - open devtools (`f12`), select the elements tab,  ctrl+f to find in the DOM, and search `iframe` and `frame` - then scroll up/down to see if your element is within any given frame

Comment: Your identifier i can't rewrite for you as it depends how it looks in the DOM

Comment: @RichEdwards it works now add it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution discussed in the comments was to add a wait.

Add this once when you create the driver object:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```